# How do I make sure the path in a Scala Spray URI does not have a trailing slash?

Tags: scala, akka, spray

I believe that my code is failing because the Spray URI is being sent to the server with a trailing slash. How do I ensure there is no trailing slash?

I am writing client authentication code in Scala using Spray. It does a dance with the various servers, gets user credentials with a ScalaFX WebView and the server sends URL of the form: https://server.com/path/to/start?st=abc123.

I haven't quite proved it by I'm fairly sure that in the background Spray is turning this into https://server.com/path/to/start**/**?st=abc123 (note the / between the end of the path and the query).

Answer (score 1):

There are two directives in `Spray-Routing` toolkit in `FileAndResourceDirectives` module: `stripLeadingSlash` and `withTrailingSlash`, both returns boolean. Example from my project:

```
lazy val staticPath =
  staticPrefixes          &
  cache(simpleRouteCache) &
  encodeResponse(Gzip)    &
  extract(ctx => !withTrailingSlash(ctx.request.uri.path))
```

Comment: Oh, so Spray-Routing is for clients, too? I was assuming it was only for servers.

Comment: @Sarge routing is just a DSL for mapping HTTP requests onto your business logic

Comment: Having done a lot of staring at the source code around spray-can I can see that the spray-routing toolkit settings don't configure it. I did eventually solve my problem. Sadly, I can't accept this answer. :-(